# UISlider not taking up full width

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I've made a full width (constrained to edge 0 on both sides) but there are a couple of pixels not used, see image below:

[image]

I've heard this is due to leaving space for the thumb slider?

Are there any ways to fill this small hole in?

I thought about placing a small view where the gap is to plug it, but this seems pretty rough and hacky :(

Thanks!

Slider set up:

```
class TrackProgressSlider : BiggerThumbTouchUISlider {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.minimumValue = 0
        self.maximumValue = 100
        self.value = 0
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 2.0)
        self.setThumbImage(UIImage(named: "progress-marker-half")!, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        self.minimumTrackTintColor = UIColor(hexString: "#f2f2f2")
        self.maximumTrackTintColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of `trackRectForBounds(_ :)`

```
class CustomSlider: UISlider {
  override func trackRectForBounds(bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var trackRect = super.trackRectForBounds(bounds)
    trackRect.size.width = bounds.width
    trackRect.origin.x = 0
    return trackRect
  } 
}
```